# What is meant by plugin goal in Maven speak?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am a newbie to Maven . I am reading up [Maven - The complete reference](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom.html) and came across the term Plugin Goals under the `Build settings`  category of a pom.xml file :

> In this section, we customize the behavior of the default Maven build.
>   We can change the location of source and tests, we can add new
>   plugins, we can attach plugin goals to the lifecycle, and we can
>   customize the site generation parameters.

Can you please explain with an example what is meant by `attaching plugin goal to the lifecycle`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plugin goal is a thing that a plugin does. Attaching a plugin goal to the lifecycle is saying to maven: when you are going through the lifecycle and are in this phase, trigger this plugin to do whatever the plugin does. This might sound rather confusing, so let's go through an example:

I want to deploy my application to the server each time I call `mvn install`. For this, in the `build` section of the pom , I add the following configuration:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
            <configuration>
                            ...
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-jar</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Take a look at the `execution` part: this describes how to attach the `deploy` goal of the `jboss-as-maven-plugin` to the `install` phase of the build lifecycle.

For further explanation of the maven lifecycle and it's phases, read [**this**](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)